# Is there any way to remove a shadow class from Robolectric?

Tags: android, testing, shadow, robolectric

[Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric) has a shadow class named `ShadowMatrix` but I don't want to use it. How to remove it from robolectric? I hope to use original `Matrix` class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work. In android.jar are only stubs of classes and methods (methods without body). That's the reason you're using Robolectric to run tests outside Android system.

That what you can do is to make a fork from [github repository](https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric), change the ShadowMatrix implementation, build and use it with your project.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. But I find it hard to provide a custom `Matrix` which is similar to android's matrix, because there are some native methods in `android.graphics.Matrix`, I can't provide proper implementation for them.

Comment: I suppose you're trying to test computations on matrixes. I don't know if it's good or not to test it, I don't know your problem. Maybe mocking is what you need?

Comment: I need to get the 9 values from matrix, and calculate the final rotate/scale/transX/Y. I decide not to test them since I think it's not easy to mock it. Thanks ~

Answer (score 0):

This may not help with the specific issue regarding `Matrix`, but I had a similar need for another class, `ShadowCountDownTimer` in one test. I was able to bypass the shadow by providing an alternate shadow which doesn't alter/add behavior of `CountDownTimer`:

```
// Shadow with no additional behavior
@Implements(CountDownTimer.class)
public static class DefaultCountDownTimer {
}

// Use this shadow just for this test
@Config(shadows = DefaultCountDownTimer.class)
@Test
public void testSomething() {
}
```

Comment: i also wonder why robolectric(4.5) ShadowCountDownTimer not work as expect, i cant find any document about this issue